# Не компилируется программа, работающая с указателями и адресами

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели, память

Пишу программу, позволяющую убедиться, что '\0' является терминирующим символом при выводе массива символов через стандартный поток cout. Однако, программа не компилируется. Вот исходный её код:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};   // массив, занимающий 4 байта, то есть 1 int
    int &addr = &a + 1;                 // взятие адреса массива a и увеличение его на 1 int
    addr  = {'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'};      // запись ещё одного массива сразу же после a
    cout << a << endl;                  // ожидается "abcdefg", т.к. 'e' в памяти идёт сразу после 'd'
    return 0;
}
```

Почему эта программа не работает? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Даже если исправить в этой программе синтаксические ошибки выкинув строчки `// взятие адреса...` и `// запись ещё...` она будет нерабочей. Дело в том, что при вызове `cout << a << endl; ` вы должны обеспечить, чтобы массив `a` завершался нулевым символом. Если хотите убедиться, что вывод заканчивается на нулевом символе, то запишите его в массив `char a[4] = {'a', 'b', '\0', 'c', 'd'}; ` или даже проще `::std::cout << "ab\0cd";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте построчно...

```
char a[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};   // массив, занимающий 4 байта, то есть 1 int
```

Без вопросов.

```
int &addr = &a + 1;                 // взятие адреса массива a и увеличение его на 1 int
```

Первое - объявлена **ссылка** на `int`, а не указатель, второе - от массива адрес не берется, `a` сам по себе указатель на первый свой элемент. Но даже если вы объявите указатель на `int`, и просто напишете `a` -

```
int *addr = a + 1;
```

то получится, что вы указателю `addr` пытаетесь присвоить указатель на `char`, что компилятор просто так позволить не может. Да и `+1` сработает просто как указатель на следующий элемент массива, т.е. на `'b'`.

Но допустим даже, что вы сделали так

```
char * addr = a + 4;
```

т.е. указываете за конец массива `a`. Но следующая строка

```
addr  = {'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'};      // запись ещё одного массива сразу же после a
```

опять же бессмысленна как синтаксически - это **не** объявление массива `addr`, так что через `{}` работать нельзя. В лучшем случае нужно сделать `strcpy(arrd,"efg")`.

Но это неверно и семантически - память за пределами вашего массива `a` вам не выделена. Там могут располагаться всякие важные вещи, а вы прямо туда пишете.

Так что надо заранее выделять место, типа

```
char a[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char * addr = a + 4;
strcpy(addr,"efg");
```

Вот так сработает...

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, почему в таком случае не работает код:
```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 char a[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};   // массив, занимающий 4 байта, то есть 1 int
 char * addr = a + 4;                // взятие адреса массива a и увеличение его на 1 int
 addr = {'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'};       // запись ещё одного массива сразу же после a
 cout << a << endl;                  // ожидается "abcdefg", т.к. 'e' в памяти идёт сразу после 'd'
 return 0;
}
```
Прошу прощения за отсутствие переноса строк, не работает по какой-то причине.

Comment: Еще раз - такая конструкция `addr = {'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'};` возможна только при инициализации массива. Присвоение массивов в С/С++ невозможно. Например, вы не можете написать `char a[5]; char b[5]; a = b;`. А в ващем случае `addr` вообще не массив, а указатель. И вы можете присвоить ему только какой-то другой адрес. Указывал в одно место, стал указывать в другое... Вы же не ждете, что в `addr = a + 4` в место, куда указывает `addr`, что-то скопируется?

Comment: Большое спасибо! Только вот ещё вопрос возник: строка `cout << &a - &addr << endl;`, которая должна выводить разницу адресов первых элементов массивов, не работает. В чём здесь ошибка?

Comment: `&addr` - это просто адрес, по которому расположена переменная? а не адрес, который в ней содержится. Вычитание адресов вообще-то имеет смысл только для элементов одного массива, остальное - UB. Но в нашем случае, раз мы получали addr как `a+4`, это допустимо, только надо писать `cout << a - addr` (или `cout << addr - a`).